# How can i pass two params @Path and @PathParam

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create authentification method using java angular js and mysql. I know how to pass one parameter but I couldn't pass two can you please help me.

Here is my DAO method :

```
public Client authentifier(int numerocompte,String mdp) {

            System.out.println(numerocompte + mdp);

            try {
            Connection con = Connexion.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from client WHERE numerocompte = ? AND mdp = ?");
            ps.setInt(1, numerocompte);
            ps.setString(2, mdp);
            Client e = new Client();
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                e.setIdclient(rs.getInt("idclient"));
                e.setNomcomplet(rs.getString("nomcomplet"));
                e.setMail(rs.getString("mail"));
                e.setNumerocompte(rs.getInt("numerocompte"));
                e.setMdp(rs.getString("mdp"));

            }
            rs.close();
            return e;

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erreur avec  authentifier() -->" + e.getMessage());
                return (null);
            }

        }
```

Here is my controller method in wehere I would Like to pass the 2 params :

```
@GET
    @Path("authentifier/{numerocompte}{mdp}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Client authentifier(@PathParam("numerocompte , mdp") int numerocompte, String mdp) {
        ClientDao dao = new ClientDao();
        System.out.println(numerocompte);
        return dao.authentifier(numerocompte,mdp);
    }
```

and here is the angular js line where also I'll pass the 2 params :

```
$http.get('rest/client/authentifier/'+$scope.nouveauClient.numerocompte+$scope.nouveauClient.mdp).then(function(data){
                 alert(data.data);
                })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All it takes is a additional `@PathParam("mdp")` annotation in the signature of your controller method.

```
@GET
@Path("authentifier/{numerocompte}/{mdp}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Client authentifier(@PathParam("numerocompte") int numerocompte, 
                           @PathParam("mdp") String mdp) {

    ClientDao dao = new ClientDao();
    System.out.println(numerocompte);
    return dao.authentifier(numerocompte,mdp);
}
```

Furthermore, make sure you specify your path well. In your example you declared

```
@Path("authentifier/{numerocompte}{mdp}")
```

JAX-RS won't be able to know where `numerocompte` start and where it ends. Separate them from each other like this

```
@Path("authentifier/{numerocompte}/{mdp}")
```

and then

```
$http.get('rest/client/authentifier/'+$scope.nouveauClient.numerocompte+'/'+$scope.nouveauClient.mdp).then(function(data){
             alert(data.data);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a `@PathParam("pathParamName")` for each method parameter

```
public Client authentifier(
    @PathParam("numerocompte") int numerocompte, 
    @PathParam("mdp") String mdp
)
```

and make sure you follow the path specified.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the slash between `numerocompte`and `mdp` at your `@Path`annotation.

Your `authentifier` function should be like the following

```
@GET
@Path("authentifier/{numerocompte}/{mdp}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Client authentifier(@PathParam("numerocompte") int numerocompte, @PathParam("mdp") String mdp) {
    ...
}
```

And the same in your Angular code

```
$http.get('rest/client/authentifier/'+$scope.nouveauClient.numerocompte+'/'+$scope.nouveauClient.mdp).then(function(data) { alert(data.data); })
```